# CATiledLayer blinks after zoom

Tags: uiscrollview, calayer, catiledlayer

I have UIScrollView with BIG subview with lots small CATiledLayers displaying images.

With zoomDidEnd I set new scale:

```
[tilesContainer setContentScaleFactor:scale];
```

cause redraw tilesContainer view with all it's layers with:

```
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
```

And I get perfect result: detailed images after zoom.

But there is a **blink** of all those layers (when loading new data).

Is it possible to hide it somehow?

I need to hold the old images in layers till load the new one.

Thanks a lot for *any* help!

Answer (score 0):

subclass the CATiledLayer and return fadeDuration of 0 to disbale the "blink".

**fadeDuration**
The time, in seconds, that newly added images take to "fade-in" to the rendered representation of the tiled layer.
The default implementation returns 0.25 seconds.